# Count length of one input field and print it in another with Gravity Forms and Javascript

Tags: javascript, wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

I am using Gravity Forms for Wordpress and I am trying to figure out how to count the length of characters a user types into one of my input boxes and print that number to another input box in the same form.  I think this can be done with Javascript but I am a total newb and well here is my very watered down effort.  Just so you can see what I am trying to do.

```
<!-- edited -->
 <form>
  <input name="input_10" id="input_1_10" type="text" value="" class="small" tabindex="1">
  <input name="input_2" id="input_1_2" type="text" value="" class="medium" tabindex="2">
  <div style="padding:10px 15px; font-family:sans-serif !important;">
     <p id="preview" style="text-align:center;font-size:22px;font-weight:bold;">Sample Text</p>
  </div>
</form>

<script>
    var bank = document.getElementById("input_1_2");
    var countNum = document.getElementById("input_1_10");
    bank.addEventListener("keyup", function(e) {
        countNum.value = bank.value.length;
    });

    document.getElementById("preview").innerHTML= countNum.value;




</script>
```

So the user will type their "message" in #input_1_10 and i need a way to count the characters(preferably without counting spaces) and print them in #input_1_2 before the user submits the form.

****  EDIT: I would also like to know how to write the value of #input_1_2 in to the paragraph with the ID of #preview.  ****

Thanks for looking ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an `eventListener` to the first input.  In this case, whenever the user presses and releases a key, the length of the input will be displayed in the second input.

```
<form>
    <input name="input_10" id="input_1_10" type="text" value="" class="small" tabindex="1">
    <input name="input_2" id="input_1_2" type="text" value="" class="medium" tabindex="2">
</form>

<script>
    var bank = document.getElementById("input_1_10");
    var countNum = document.getElementById("input_1_2");
    bank.addEventListener("keyup", function(e) {
        countNum.value = bank.value.length;
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I was close!  How could I elaborate on that a bit to also write the value of #input_1_10 in to a div?

Would it be similar to this in the Javascript if I have a paragraph tag with an id of "preview"?

[updated code above]

sorry still learning ;)

Comment: What you have is actually pretty close.  Remember that the `function(e)` part is run every time a key is pressed, so you want to put your `innerHTML` stuff inside that function.  Good luck :)