# How to count lengths of multiple text inputs and print them into corresponding number fields with Gravity Forms

Tags: javascript, gravity-forms-plugin

I'm trying to count the number of characters entered into 4 text input fields and print the character count into their corresponding number fields like so:

- Character count text input1 -> Number field 1
- Character count text input2 -> Number field 2
- Character count text input3 -> Number field 3
- Character count text input4 -> Number field 4

I found this code snippet in another answer, but its just working for a single input field: [Count length of one input field and print it in another with Gravity Forms and Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18198117/count-length-of-one-input-field-and-print-it-in-another-with-gravity-forms-and-j):

```
<form>
    <input name="input_10" id="input_1_10" type="text" value="" class="small" tabindex="1">
    <input name="input_2" id="input_1_2" type="text" value="" class="medium" tabindex="2">
</form>

<script>
    var bank = document.getElementById("input_1_10");
    var countNum = document.getElementById("input_1_2");
    bank.addEventListener("keyup", function(e) {
        countNum.value = bank.value.length;
    });
</script>
```

As I'm a total newbie to javascript and jQuery, I don't know how to modify this snippet to get it working. Any ideas or suggestions?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You could repeat repeat `addEventListener` for all inputs, or you could do it like this

```js
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('.small');

inputs.forEach(function(input){
 input.addEventListener('keyup', function(e){
  this.nextElementSibling.value = this.value.length;
 })
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Input Demo</title>
</head>
<body>
<label for="inputOne">Input One</label> 
<input name="input_10" id="input_1_10" type="text" value="" class="small" tabindex="1">
    <input name="input_2" id="input_1_2" type="text" value="" class="medium" tabindex="2">
<hr/> 
<label for="inputTwo">Input Two</label> 
<input name="input_10" id="input_1_10" type="text" value="" class="small" tabindex="1">
    <input name="input_2" id="input_1_2" type="text" value="" class="medium" tabindex="2">
 
</body>
</html>
```

Notice, this code depends on the html markup, so it worn't work if you have anything else between two inputs, `nextElementSibling` selects the next element from current node. [nextElementSibling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NonDocumentTypeChildNode/nextElementSibling) on mdn

Comment: thanks for the quick reply. Unfortunately this doesn't work either, as gravity forms wraps all of my inputs into list elements. I came up with another idea: What might also work is the "prepopulate field" function of gravity forms as demonstrated in this article: [link]https://www.gravityhelp.com/documentation/article/gform_field_value_parameter_name/ Point 4 (Populate multiple fields using one function) of the article seems to be the closest fit to what I am trying to achieve. Any idea on how to modify the function so that I get the character count instead of a fix value?

Comment: Sorry that it didn't worked, character count of what? you can use php `strlen` function to get length of a string.