# Count Byte of textbox.text (ASP.NET, C#)

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to count byte of the text at the textbox.

At ~~.aspx, there are a textbox(txtContent) and a label(lblByte)
I want to count the byte of the text which was typed by client to txtContent "realtime", not like after clicking the button.

```
lblByte.Text = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(txtContent.Text).Length.ToString() + "byte";
```

This is the code I want to run at ~~.aspx.cs, which will show counted byte at label

I wanted to use onkeyup, but it does not work well.
If you guys have any solutions, please answer to this question.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried using the `input` event? its compatible with `input` and `textarea` elements

Comment: I would not take that approach. Counting a textbox length server side (c# code) just to show it "real time" in a Label while the user types would require some client-server communication (javascript ajax calls). i would suggest using simple javascript (either pure JS or some javascript API like JQuery) and dealing with the problem you say you faced.

Comment: @nickzoum I have to get text from the textbox, so i was not thinking 'bout it. is it possible to do it with input?

Comment: This looks to me like a [X-Y problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). You should be asking about about a javascript coding problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Count length of one input field and print it in another with Gravity Forms and Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18198117/count-length-of-one-input-field-and-print-it-in-another-with-gravity-forms-and-j)

Answer (score 0):

use the following encoding function to count the bytes in a string

```
lblByte.Text=System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetByteCount(txtContent.Text)+"Bytes";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var test2 = "srikanth";
var result = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetByteCount(test2) + " Bytes";
Console.WriteLine("Hello World test1 : "  +result);
```

Output:
Hello World test1 : 8 Bytes

Comment: For more information you can refer to this link:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding.getbytecount?view=netframework-4.7.2